# get only last page when I try to scrape daily HTML tables with selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webrscrape data for my project. And this is the first time I try to do webscraping. That is the data for prices, which lies on website. The problem is that I need it for all days starting from 2020, meaning on website I will need to choose a date and then only then I will see a table. I need all of these tables.

Most importantly, seems that page address doesn't change if I change the date

I try to use silenium, but somehow get only last page data still. Can you probably suggest how I can correct it.

That is what i do:

```
#Make preporations
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

s = Service('C:/Users/Имя/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

#Get the webpage
driver.get("https://www.opcom.ro/pp/grafice_ip/raportPIPsiVolumTranzactionat.php?lang=en")

#Get elements
xpath = "//*[@id='tab_PIP_Vol']"
table_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
        (By.XPATH, "//*[@id ='tab_PIP_Vol']")))
for table_element in table_elements:
    for row in table_element.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath):
        print(row.text)
```

The output I get is like this 9 (I put only for 1sr interval, it is for 24):

```
Trading Zone Interval ROPEX_DAM_H [Euro/MWh] Traded Volume [MWh] Traded Buy Volume [MWh] Traded Sell Volume [MWh]
Romania
1
192.23
2,985.4
2,774.9
2,985.4
```

As you can see, only last page values, when I expect much more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = "https://www.opcom.ro/pp/grafice_ip/raportPIPsiVolumTranzactionat.php?lang=en"

all_data = []
for d in pd.date_range("01/01/2020", "31/01/2020"): # <-- change date range here
    data = {
        "day": f"{d.day:02}",
        "month": f"{d.month:02}",
        "year": f"{d.year:04}",
        "buton": "Refresh",
    }
    print(f"Reading {d=}")

    while True:
        try:
            df = pd.read_html(
                requests.post(url, data=data, verify=False, timeout=3).text
            )[1]
            break
        except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
            continue

    df["Date"] = d
    all_data.append(df)

df_out = pd.concat(all_data).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_out)
df_out.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

This will iteratate days specified in `pd.date_range`, downloads the data, creates one dataframe and saves it to CSV (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]